# Why is function <= function true, but NaN <= NaN false in ECMAscript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the mystery of comparing functions:

```js
let a=function(){}
let b=function(){}
console.log(a==b)  //false
console.log(a===b) //false
console.log(a<b)   //false
console.log(a>b)   //false
console.log(a<=b)  //true !?!
console.log(a>=b)  //true !?!

console.log( (+a) <  (+b) )  //false
console.log( (+a) >  (+b) )  //false
console.log( (+a) <= (+b) )  //false
console.log( (+a) >= (+b) )  //false
```

In ECMAscript the <= operator is [described](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> RelationalExpression:RelationalExpression<=ShiftExpression
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating RelationalExpression.
> 2. Let lval be ? GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
> 4. Let rval be ? GetValue(rref).
> 5. Let r be the result of performing Abstract Relational Comparison rval < lval with LeftFirst equal to false.
> 6. ReturnIfAbrupt(r).
> 7. If r is true or undefined, return false. Otherwise, return true.

The Abstract Relational Comparison seems to have special cases for strings and BigInts but I think everything else should be converting to numbers. So I would expect the second set of comparisons to be equivalent to the first and yet it's not. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Abstract Relational Comparison calls [ToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive) on the arguments with a hint of `'number'`. That then calls [OrdinaryToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive) again with a hint of `'number'`.

The hint here is really just a hint; it is not required that the routine returns that type. The hint of `'number'` just causes OrdinaryToPrimitive to try calling `valueOf` before `toString`, but it will still end up calling `toString` if `valueOf` does not return a primitive.

If you provide a valueOf implementation that returns a primitive it will be used for the comparison:

```js
let a=function(){}
let b=function(){}

a.valueOf = () => 1;
b.valueOf = () => 0;

console.log( a <= b );
console.log( b <= a );
```

By default valueOf for a function returns the function itself, which is not a primitive, so toString is called instead and the functions are compared as strings.

Comment: Aha, it's like implementing IEquatable vs IComparable in C#. Comparing is different from equating.

Comment: Oh! I missed the calls to ToPrimitive that are BEFORE the type checking, so I thought it was only doing ToNumeric after the fact (which still calls ToPrimitive, but then converts the results to a number (NaN in this case)